# Why can I console.log a variable but it not be able to use in a filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, filter

I am trying to create a `React.js` blog so I have an `easybase.io` database that will hold data for my blog. There is a page where all posts are displayed, and when someone clicks on a post the post id is sent over using the `paramas` module in the `react-router-dom` package. When doing `console.log(postid)` it displays in the console but when passing it through the filter it doesn't work for some reason is there any explanation? The filter is filtering through all the posts selected from the database and only returning the object with the same id. When putting `task.id === 1` it returns with the object with an id of 1 however when putting in `task.id === postid` and `postid` is equal to 1 in the console then it returns nothing.

All posts code

```
/* eslint-disable */

import { useEasybase } from "easybase-react";

import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

export default function BlogPosts() {
  let history = useHistory();
  const { db } = useEasybase();

  const [responseData, setResponse] = useState([]);

  async function getPosts() {
    const ebData = await db("POSTS").return().all();
    setResponse(ebData);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getPosts();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {responseData.map((val, key) => {
          return (
            <div
              style={{ border: "1px solid black", margin: "1em 1em" }}
              key={key}
              onClick={() => {
                history.push(`/post/${val.id}`);
              }}
            >
              <h3>{val.title}</h3>
              <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: val.post_text }} />
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Open post code

```
/* eslint-disable */
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useEasybase } from "easybase-react";

export default function BlogPosts() {
//testing for the filter function  
const tasks = [
    {
      taskId: 1,
      taskName: "Clean the bathroom",
      taskStatus: "Complete",
    },
    {
      taskId: 2,
      taskName: "Learn filtering data in React",
      taskStatus: "To do",
    },
    {
      taskId: 3,
      taskName: "Fix the bug on React project",
      taskStatus: "To do",
    },
    {
      taskId: 4,
      taskName: "Fix the car",
      taskStatus: "Complete",
    },
  ];

  const [responseData, setResponse] = useState([]);
  const [idState, setIdState] = useState(0);

  let { postid } = useParams();

  const { db } = useEasybase();

  async function getPosts() {
    const ebData = await db("POSTS").return().all();
    setResponse(ebData);
    console.log(ebData);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getPosts();
    setIdState(postid);
    console.log(postid);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div style={{ justifyContent: "center", alignContent: "center" }}>
        {tasks
          .filter((task) => task.taskStatus === "To do")
          .map((task) => (
            <li key={task.taskId}>{task.taskName}</li>
          ))}
        {responseData
          .filter((task) => task.id === postid)
          .map((task) => (
            <li key={task.id}>{task.title}</li>
          ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: try == instead of ===

Comment: @MiladRaeisi unless you know _exactly_ why you're using `==`, you should never be using it. If your code doesn't work with `===`, fix the code leading up to the equality check, don't "solve" it by letting JS perform type coercion.

Comment: task.id === postid, should it be taskId === postid

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I'm not saying that put bug on your code, I just say try it and see if it is the problem, its better to convert string to integer but first find the problem. and oh see, you should say task.taskId not task.id

Comment: That's not what you said though, you used three words and two operators: it's always a good idea to say a little more than that if you're recommending an anti-pattern =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely cause is that `postid` from the route parameters is a string (as after all, the URL it came from is a string) while your `task.id` is a number as shown in your code.

When comparing `'1' === 1`, it'll always fail due to the types being different. Either use `==`, or better, first convert the route parameter (`postid`) to a number.

Comment: But really: never use `==`, properly validate your values, which means using `parseInt` in this case, and then also making sure to shortcut if the result of parseInt is `NaN`, because it could be.

Comment: okay thank you very much I didn't think to look if it was being passed as a string thank you so much!